# "React.jsx: type is invalid" error when unit tests run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, storybook

I'm importing components from another component package (uses Storybook) I manage. The components show up normally in the UI. But when I run tests, the tests pass but I get errors regarding the importing of these components:

```js
console.error
    Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

    > 1 | import { Button, Modal } from 'components-library';
        | ^
```

Updating `import Button, Modal from 'components-library';` which doesn't work at all, since we don't export anything as `default`.

In the component library package (uses Material UI) Button is exported as:

```js
import {
  Button as MuiButton,
  ButtonProps as MuiButtonProps,
} from '@mui/material';

export const Button = ({ children, ...rest }: ButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <MuiButton variant='text'>
      {children}
    </MuiButton>
  );
};
```

Button type shows as follows:

```
(alias) const Button: ({ children, ...rest }: ButtonProps) => react_jsx_runtime.JSX.Element
export Button
```

Could this have to do with something in the test setup? We're using React testing library and webpack.

Comment: Do you have index file in components-library folder?

Comment: @JasonMing Yes. In the `src/components/index.ts` folder (where this component is located), I have `export * from './Button';`. Then in the root `src` dir, there is an index.ts file with `export * from './components';`. The components appear as expected in the separate package I'm importing them into, so I know they're being exported correctly.

Comment: How do you import Button in test file?

Comment: The test is for a component that uses the Button (or whatever component from this library, this isn't just an issue with the Button component).

So when I run `yarn test PageForm.test.tsx` I get an error about the components being imported from the component library in `PageForm.tsx`.

Comment: Please share me how you imported Button in PageForm.

Comment: It's the first example I provided:
`import { Button, Modal } from 'components-library';`

The warning comes from that line when I run the tests. Removing brackets just breaks it which is to be expected. I'm not sure why this is giving an unexpected type issue. It's meant to be an object.